# Adding a <use>-tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, xlink

I am trying to add a `use`-svg-tag with Javascript. Jakob Jenkov has an excellent intro to `use` here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/use-element.html

I just tried to do the same thing with JavaScript:

```
var useit = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
useit.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#a-circle");
useit.setAttribute("x", "100");
useit.setAttribute("y", "100");

svg.appendChild(useit);
```

I made a fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/yfmSm/2/

Looking at the structure created (in Google Chrome workspace) everything looks fine to me. It is just that the circle added with `use` is invisible.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`setAttributeNS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttributeNS) for setting the `href` attribute, else the attribute will belong to the default (SVG) namespace and thus not be recognized.

```
// ...
useit.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'href', "#a-circle");
// ...
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfmSm/3/)

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought I tested that, but I did not get the namespace correct. With that info I found this page, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course, which perhaps is a good overview?